# Неравномерное расположение элементов в Android

Tags: android, layout

Есть задача расположить картинки по экрану, в произвольных местах. 
Выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил задачу с помощью множественных вложений linearlayout и поиграл с весами. Но всё это выглядит очень громоздко и явно в будущем выльется в проблему.
Можно ли как-то поизящнее справится с этим?

Comment: с помощью верстки такое делать не стоит, так как будут проблемы с позиционированием на разных экранах, такое рисуют непосредственно на канве обычно (Canvas)

Comment: Для начала смотрите, например, [эти уроки](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html) (с 141-го по 160-ый). Возможно и до 176-го

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду изучать тему!